# Keras FFT layer has no effect

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, fft

Hi i'm trying to implement an FFT in my model. I isolated the fft layer to better see the effect, but when I call my model on any data it returns the input, unaffected.

Here's my code with sample data:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from keras.layers import Input, Lambda
from keras.models import Model
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np


def fftModel1D(input_shape):
    x_input = Input(input_shape)
    x = Lambda(lambda v: tf.cast(tf.spectral.fft(tf.cast(v,dtype=tf.complex64)),tf.float32))(x_input)
    return Model(inputs=x_input, outputs=[x])

model = fftModel1D((1000, 1))
testData = np.asarray([np.expand_dims(np.sin(np.linspace(0, 100, 1000)), 1)])

pred = model.predict(testData)[0]

fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2)
axes[0].plot(np.squeeze(testData))
axes[1].plot(np.squeeze(pred))
plt.show()
```

This currently shows identical plots of sin(x) while I'm expecting the FFT on the second graph.

I'm using Python 3.6.8, Keras 2.2.4, Tensorflow 1.13.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the input has 2 dimensions (shape is `(1000, 1)`), using `tf.fft2D` seems to work.